# sending multiple emails fails for the last email address

Tags: mysql, vb.net

We are facing an issue with VB.net which automates email being send with text file attachments to more than one email address.
The strange part is if we send the mail to 2 persons, then first person receives the email but not the second. 
If we add three email address, then email is received by first two email addresses but no to the third one. it keeps going this way when adding more email addresses.
Also, while executing the script a second time, email does goes to all recipients. To be precise, emails are received by all recipients on alternate execution of the script only. 
Does this have anything to do with the time taken by mail server etc? 
finally what we did to make it work is run the send email command for the last email address two times. I know this is not a permanent solution. 
Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("1.1.1.1", 25);

        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("support", "support");

        MailMessage EM1= new MailMessage("support@domain.com", "user1@domain.com ",
           "This is my subject" + " " + "  ", "Hello,");

        EM1.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"F:\WebData\TxtFiles\1.txt"));
        client.Send(EM1);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;


        MailMessage EM2 = new MailMessage("support@domain.com", "user2@domain.com",
           "This is my subject" + " " + " ", "Hello,");

        EM2.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"F:\WebData\TxtFiles\1.txt"));
        client.Send(EM2);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        MailMessage EM3 = new MailMessage("support@domain.com", "user3@domain.com",
        "This is my subject" + " " + " ", "Hello,");

        EM3.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"F:\WebData\TxtFiles\1.txt"));
        client.Send(EM3);
        client.Send(EM3);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: That looks like VB.net code. VB.net and VBScript are different languages.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I am entirely new to this(even the project). The code was written by a colleague. Should I tag this under a different tag?

Comment: I already took the liberty to fix the tags for you.

Comment: Oops.. thank you. Is there any work around for avoiding the code line "   client.Send(EM3);" for the second time?

Answer (score 0):

The first place you should check are the logs of the mail server. They should tell you what's happening with the submitted messages (accept/reject, next-hop delivery, etc.).

However, sending the same message multiple times to different recipients is bad practice anyway. Doing that is the mail server's job. Submit the message just once for all intended recipients. You can specify all recipients with a comma-separated string:

```
MailMessage EM = new MailMessage("support@example.com", _
  "user1@example.com,user2@example.com,user3@example.com", _
  "This is my subject", "Hello,");

EM.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"F:\WebData\TxtFiles\1.txt"));
client.Send(EM);
```

or add additional recipients like this:

```
MailMessage EM = new MailMessage("support@example.com", _
  "user1@example.com", "This is my subject", "Hello,");

EM.To.Add("user2@example.com");
EM.To.Add("user3@example.com");

EM.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"F:\WebData\TxtFiles\1.txt"));
client.Send(EM);
```

If you don't want the recipient to know about the other recipients, send the message to a default recipient (e.g. the sender address) and add the other recipients as BCC addresses:

```
MailMessage EM = new MailMessage("support@example.com", _
  "support@example.com", "This is my subject", "Hello,");

EM.Bcc.Add("user1@example.com");
EM.Bcc.Add("user2@example.com");
EM.Bcc.Add("user3@example.com");

EM.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"F:\WebData\TxtFiles\1.txt"));
client.Send(EM);
```